# Does the name Yoshi from Super Mario mean anything?

Tags: names

The Japanese spelling of Yoshi is Yosshii ヨッシー

I couldn't find any information regarding the origin of this name.

Is it a Japanese name ? Does it mean anything ?

It's written in katakana which suggests to me that it is not a Japanese name and has no meaning.

Comment: The name of Yoshi's species is T. Yoshisaur Munchakoopas (from [wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A8%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC#%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D)) but shortened to Yoshi as he is a famous character now.

Answer (score 8):

According to [ヨッシー in Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A8%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC#%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D):

> 「ヨッシー」という命名は、任天堂社員のあだ名に由来。
>
> (Translation: The name ヨッシー derived from a nickname of a Nintendo employee.)

So ヨッシー was the nickname of a real person in Nintendo.

Is this a common nickname in Japanese? Yes. Many Japanese surnames have よし (Usually 吉 in kanji, for example you may know [this 吉田](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuhei_Yoshida) and [this 吉田](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naoki_Yoshida)), and ヨッシー is a reasonable nickname for someone whose surname contains よし. Also note that a nickname can be written in katakana regardless of the etymology.

Comment: Also... [Yoshihiro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshihiro) is a reasonably common name.  I've known people with this name to shorten it to just "Yoshi" in informal circumstances.